# Retrieve all users from Active Directory (LDAP) using VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript, active-directory, ldap

How can I retrieve all users from Active Directory using VBScript?

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim oDomain = GetObject("LDAP://OU=YourOU,DC=YourDomain,DC=com")
For Each oUser in oDomain
  WScript.echo oUser.Get("distinguishedName")
```

Maybe this will get you running?

Comment: I think on the second line "oObject" should be "oDomain"

Comment: Does "LDAP" *need* to be uppercase?